# how to type a constant function that returns an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

this is my code:

```
interface profileProps {
  id: string
  name: string
  email: string
  link: string
}
const profile = await queryFacebookAPI("/me", { fields: "name,email,link" });
```

i tried:

```
const profile: () => profileProps = await queryFacebookAPI("/me", { fields: "name,email,link" })
const profile = await queryFacebookAPI("/me", { fields: "name,email,link" }):profileProps;
```

and it still don't work

```
console.log('profile.name',profile.name)
```

i get an error that states the property name does not exist on type void?

Comment: `const profile: profileProps = await ...`…?

Comment: what is queryFacebookAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getFbProfile(fields: string = "name,email,link"): Promise<profileProps> {
   const res = await await queryFacebookAPI("/me", { fields });
   const profileData = await res.json();

   return profileData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[check the Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4agjm)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
interface profileProps {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  link: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  profile = {} as profileProps;

  print() {
    this.profile.name = "Name";
    console.log(this.profile.name);
  }
}
```